# Error Index (zero based) must be greater than or equal to zero and less than the size of the argument list

Tags: c#, string, formatting

I have the below code:

```
a = "Return {1}"
ItalicsCloseTag = "</i>";
ItalicsOpenTag = "<i>";
b = "Delete {0}?"
c = string.Format(b, string.Concat(ItalicsOpenTag, HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(a), ItalicsCloseTag));
```

I get below  error on the above statement.

```
 System.FormatException was unhandled by user code
 Additional information: Index (zero based) must be greater than or equal to zero and less than the size of the argument list.
```

I tried with

```
b = "Delete {{{0}}}?"
```

and got FormatException exception and

```
b = "Delete {{0}}?"
```

and got out put as "Delete {0}?"

Help? I'm basically looking for the statement to output 'Delete *Return {1}*?'

Comment: What do you *intend* to happen here?

Comment: That's not valid code (where are the definitions), and ***I get an error*** is too vague. Read [ask]

Comment: "I get an error on the above statement." > I don't. Please clarify *what* error you get. Second: your code doesn't compile.

Comment: Most probably - there is a problem with {1} not with {0}

Comment: After adding some minimal additions, Variable 'c' results in 'Delete <i>Return {1}</i>?'. What dit you expect it to be?

Comment: Edited the question.

@Björn Boxstart I'm not getting that output. I get a FormatException

Comment: Still not failing here. Did you put this code in a new project and test it yourself?

Comment: I can only imagine that this error (index blah blah) occurs when you're using the result (c) in an additional string.Format command (string.Format(c, myValForC)). Because string 'c' contains '{1}' where string.Format always expects placeholders starting from 0 ({0}).

Answer (score 1):

Whatever you're trying to do, I can't image that code is the best way of going about it.

As it is, "c" ends up being `Delete <i>Return {1}</i>?`

I assume you understand string.format and want "{0}" and "{1}" to be placeholders in which you'll put some sensible values?

Is something like `string.Format("<i>Delete {0} Return {1}</i>", valueFor0, valueFor1);` what you're after?

Comment: With that question at the end this sounds too speculative to be useful.